# Why can I switch to a user but not run a script as it

Tags: bash, sudo, su

If I try to switch to a user using command `sudo su - kshitiz`. It works fine and switches without asking for a password.

But if I try to run a script as that user it asks me for a password.

```
sudo -u kshitiz bash << EOF
> cat /home/ri/secret.txt
> EOF
```

Why is this so?

Update:

```
User ksh may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - kshitiz
```

Comment: What does `sudo -l` show for permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a sudo configuration which allows running a login shell, but not directly running an arbitrary program.

If the user has a restricted account, i.e. if the user's login shell is a program that only performs a few specific commands, then this is a security restriction; allowing you to run bash would bypass that security restriction.

If the user's login shell is an ordinary command shell such as bash, then this configuration is silly because you can run arbitrary commands anyway. You just have to run the exact required command via `sudo`, and since that runs a shell, pass the commands you want to run to that shell.

```
sudo /bin/su - kshitiz <<'EOF'
cat /home/ri/secret.txt
EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

As you determined, `sudo` is set up to only allow `sudo su - kshitiz`, so your second command is bound to fail.

In any case, you're not going through the same user transitions.

```
sudo su - kshitiz
```

runs `su - kshitiz` as `root`; if you can `sudo` to `root` with no password, this will not ask for a password at all since `su -` as `root` changes users without asking for a password.

```
sudo -u kshitiz
```

asks `sudo` to switch to `kshitiz` directly, which requires its own configuration if you don't want it to ask for a password.

If the user were allowed to run anything,

```
sudo su - kshitiz -c bash ...
```

would work. You could also configure `sudo` to allow

```
sudo -u kshitiz ...
```

with no password.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that /etc/sudoers is not using secure_path or env_reset. You might also try using:

```
sudo -E -u user   # -E overrides env_reset.
```

I don't understand the widespread use of "sudo su .." it's redundant.

- sudo -i : run an interactive login shell (reads /root/.bashrc and
- /root/.profile) sudo -s : run a non-login interactive shell (reads
  /root/.bashrc)